# Keep getting " Failed to reload daemon: Failed to activate service ‘org.freedesktop.systemd1’ "

Tags: apt, server, updates, services

Ubuntu 20.04.6

About 3 weeks ago I started getting the message " Failed to reload daemon: Failed to activate service ‘org.freedesktop.systemd1’ " doing a system update.

But the server seems to be running OK and accessing web-site on server has no slowdown. But on every update I get that message.

I’ve hunted on-line for a solution found a couple, but none seem to work. I’m also worried that a reboot might actually fail as a couple of people reported that side-effect.

Are there any words of wisdom that could help me out?

Kind Regards, Nigel.